# Spacing between items in quote environment

Tags: spacing

I am wondering how to change the spacing between block quotes within one single quote environment. I would like to change this globally, and without having to use an environment other than quote.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

What I am trying to do is to change the amount of space that appears on the page between lipsum[2] and lipsum[3], without thereby changing the spacing between items in other list environments.

Comment: Of course, after working on this for hours, I figured it out a few minutes after posting here. One answer seems to be to use `\makeatletter \renewenvironment{quote}{\list{}{\parsep  8\p@ \@plus\p@} \item\relax}{\endlist} \makeatother` , where "8" can be adjusted larger or smaller. There may be other solutions as well.

Comment: Did you consider the `quoting` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `quote` environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewenvironment{quote}
 {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin\parsep 12pt plus 2pt}%
 \item\relax}
 {\endlist}

 \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
 \lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]